Extracting specific values from a body message in python
I am sending a body message which includes two sets of data in the following format:
Updated as follows:
String 1 between ! and :
String 2 between % and =
This works generally however, I do have chracters I still need to remove.
import os
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from twilio.rest import Client 
import re
load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)
twilio_client = Client()

@app.route('/incoming/sms', methods = ['POST'])
def incoming_sms():  
    incoming_message     = request.form["Body"]
    
    p = re.search('!(.*):', incoming_message)
    # get extracted phone
    whatsapp_to          = p.group(1)
    
    m = re.search('%(.*)=', incoming_message)
    # get extracted message
    extract_message      = m.group(1)
   
    # Clean up message content 
    body_message         = re.sub("[+$@&%{}:=!]"," ",extract_message)
             
    from_number          = os.getenv("TWILIO_WHATSAPP_NUMBER")
    twilio_from          = os.getenv("TWILIO_FROM_NUMBER")
    message              = f"An TRAKSIFY event has been reported. The event message is: {body_message}"
    twilio_client.messages.create(body=message, from_=f"whatsapp:{twilio_from}", to=f"whatsapp:{whatsapp_to}")
    return Response()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


Where is the part of the code that includes "Updated as follows:"?

And what is your question?

This has been the updated part:
String 1 between ! and :
String 2 between % and =


Seems like I could solve as following.
incoming_message     = request.form["Body"]

p = re.search('!(.*):', incoming_message)
# get extracted phone and replace + if available
whatsapp_to          = p.group(1)
whatsapp_to          = whatsapp_to.replace("%2B", "")
whatsapp_to          = re.sub("[+$@&%{}:=!]","",whatsapp_to)

m = re.search('%(.*)=', incoming_message)
# get extracted message and remove unwanted characters
extract_message      = m.group(1)
body_message         = re.sub("[+$@&%{}:=!]"," ",extract_message)
clean_message        = body_message.rstrip('%0A')
clean_message        = clean_message.replace(" 3A", ":")


It's still unclear what the question is that this is the answer to.

Basically I am posting to the Twilio API from a web application. Twilio forwards the message to my Python app. The Twilio response contains a body message, inside the body message are two strings which I need to identify and split. The strings are both identified by specific start and end characters. The challenge was to extract the two strings from the single body payload clean them so that both values can be forwarded to another API.
